# C# Linking element of List

Tags: c#

I'm thinking of a way to create a link or reference to a List of Strings. My situation is that I'm creating ARP table and I need to save IP (as String) of my interface that captured response msg. Interface's IP address is saved in List`<String>`.

```
ARP_Table_entry(System.Net.IPAddress host_ip_addr, System.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress host_mac_addr, int position)
    {
        this.host_ip_addr = host_ip_addr;
        this.host_mac_addr = host_mac_addr;
        this.time = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        this.local_inter = ??;
    }
```

What I don't want to do, is to assign local_inter smt like list.ElementAt(0), because when I change IP address on the interface (List gets updated w/ new one), value in entry won't change - and I would have to do foreach for every entry (not bad, but...)

Instead I'm looking for solution, that will "link" that specific List-element to local_inter parameter - so changing IP in List will result in automatic update in every entry that contained old one.

Comment: Basically you want to bind an element of your list to your `local_inter` ?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can control code for `ARP_Table_entry` just make `local_inter` property that returns value from that mysterious list:

```
class ARP_Table_entry
{
   List<string> mysteriousList;
   int pos; 
   public ARP_Table_entry(List<string> mysteriousList, int pos,...)
   {
      this.mysteriousList = mysteriousList;
      this.pos = pos;
      ...
   }

    // TODO: add null check/position verification as needed
    string local_inter => mysteriousList[pos];
     // or {get { return mysteriousList[pos];} for C# 5 and below
    ...
```

You can also use `Func<string>` as type or `local_inter` if you want to use fields for some reason:

```
class ARP_Table_entry
{
    public Func<string> local_inter;
    ...

    public ARP_Table_entry(List<string> mysteriousList, int pos,...)
    {
      local_inter = () => mysteriousList[pos];
      ...
    }
```

Note that either approach will not protect you from replacing list altogether with `originalMysteriousList = new List<string>()`.

Another option is to have more complex type to store list of IPs that will notify about its changes (similar to `ObesrvableCollection`) and update fields on change in the collection.